# How to know the total storage space of Phone or SD on WP8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Is there have a way to know the total storage space of Phone or SD through WP8.1 API? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will prefix this answer with: There is no officially supported way to get size of the storage or the amount of free space on the phone's internal storage or the SD card in Windows Phone 8.1.

But taking no for an answer is really boring.

#### The drive the app is installed on:

- [GetDiskFreeSpaceExW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937(v=vs.85).aspx) works on the isolated storage folder of the app.

Now we just need to get the drive we aren't installed on:

#### For SD when installed on internal:

- [GetDiskFreeSpaceExW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937(v=vs.85).aspx) works on a folder on the SD card - **only if you are deployed from VS**, installing from the store stops this from working.

#### Inconsistent Results:

- The [System.FreeSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760719(v=vs.85).aspx) folder property sometimes works. I can't seem to nail a pattern to this.